# How to give access to a user to a view, but not to the table the view is using?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a user (called **myUser**) which has *db_datareader* role on **myCustomDatabase**.

**myCustomDatabase** and **MSDB** are owned by **sa** user.

I've enable chaining (it's already enabled on **MSDB**):

```
ALTER DATABASE myCustomDatabase SET DB_CHAINING ON;
```

I created a view on **myCustomDatabase** as following:

```
CREATE VIEW myCustomDatabase.dbo.myView AS
    SELECT run_date  FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory
```

I would like **myUser** be able to call this view, and not the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory // Should not work
SELECT * FROM myCustomDatabase.dbo.myView // Should work
```

With described permissions I get following error:

```
The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'sysjobhistory', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'.
```

Where am I wrong with db chaining?

---

**Edit:**

Here the script I run with succeed on a database test, but I still don't succeed to apply this changes on an already existing database:

```
CREATE DATABASE myCustomDatabase ;
GO

ALTER DATABASE myCustomDatabase SET DB_CHAINING ON;
USE myCustomDatabase ;
GO

CREATE VIEW dbo.myView AS
    SELECT run_date  FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory
GO

// The login myUser already exists on my server
CREATE USER myUser FROM LOGIN myUser;

GRANT SELECT ON dbo.myView TO myUser;
```

Here the script I run on my already existing DB:

```
/*CREATE DATABASE thisDatabaseAlreadyExists ;
GO*/

ALTER DATABASE thisDatabaseAlreadyExists SET DB_CHAINING ON;
USE thisDatabaseAlreadyExists ;
GO

create  VIEW dbo.myView AS
    SELECT run_date  FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory
GO

/* The user already exist, he's got db_datareader role on thisDatabaseAlreadyExists*/
/*CREATE USER myUser FROM LOGIN myUser;*/

GRANT SELECT ON dbo.myView TO myUser;
```

Comment: Followed your steps outlined on a test database and it worked fine for me. Hate to ask, but did you double check everything? `sa` ownership, user permissions, etc.?

Comment: @JohnM thanks, it was a sa-ownership problem, due to a confusing interface...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a problem about the database owner.

Even if you can see an owner on this interface:
[image]

Be sure that an owner is entered into files tab:
[image]